# vb.net loop through list box contains path for rtf files then convert to html code then insert to datagridview

Tags: vb.net, loops, gridview

I have a problem with vb.net code, after i finished with all codes that get files from path then loop through this list to get RTF text then convert it to HTML... until here everything is okay
**my problem starts here>>>** inserting the result to new row in datagridview it just does this to first row, then stops after that!
here's the codes

```
     For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        'get RTF files...
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString(), 
        RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
        RichTextBox1.SelectAll()
        RichTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = 
        HorizontalAlignment.Right

        'Convert to html method...
        converttohtml()

        'just for fallow the process
        MsgBox("Ok " + i.ToString())

        'insert new row with the html result
        DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(i, New String() {RichTextBox2.Text, RichTextBox1.Text})

        'increase progress by one
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    Next
```

Comment: How many items are there in `ListBox1`? Have you tried [stepping through your code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger) to see what happens after inserting the first row?

Comment: The loop works fine, i tested it by adding another column which has i index .tostring ... and it work find ...

Comment: also tested it by adding text before converter it and also works fine....!!

Comment: What do you mean by _"it works fine"_? Do you get more than one MsgBox but only one row is inserted? Have you tried stepping through your code as I said before?

Comment: i mean the loop works fine i tested it, yes i did step through the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem fixed... by help of a freelancer ... here's the code

```
    'add column to datagridview ...
    Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    col.DataPropertyName = "cellvalue"
    col.HeaderText = "Article"
    col.Name = "Article"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(col)

    'second coulmn...
    Dim cols As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    cols.DataPropertyName = "cellnumber"
    cols.HeaderText = "number"
    cols.Name = "number"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cols)

    'third coulmn...
    Dim colsa As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    colsa.DataPropertyName = "cellnumber"
    cols.HeaderText = "number"
    colsa.Name = "number"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colsa)
    DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
    DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None

    ProgressBar1.Value = 0

    Dim x As Integer = 0
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        'get RTF files...
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString(), 
RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
        RichTextBox1.SelectAll()
        RichTextBox1.SelectionAlignment = 
HorizontalAlignment.Right

        'Convert to html method...
        converttohtml()

        'just for fallow the process
        MsgBox("Ok " + i.ToString())

        'insert new row with the html result
        DataGridView1.Rows.Insert(i, New String() 
{RichTextBox2.Text, RichTextBox1.Text, xstring})

        'increase progress by one
        ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

cells just needed to be wrap... BY  M P.